# How can I determine Percent to Goal with a range that includes negative numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I have developed a scorecard system that uses results from a survey which can have a range of values between -100 and 100. The scorecard takes the various results and assigns a percent-to-goal value to those results. In this case, the goal is 15. Since the goal is so low, a straight percentage varies wildly. It's not uncommon for a result to be -30 (producing a -200%), or 30 (producing 200%).

When I look at this result alongside the other values on the scorecard, the small target and large range causes large fluctuations in the results. Of course, the idea is to be at or above 100% with a percent-to-goal measurement.

Would it make sense to normalize the survey results into a 200 point scale and then generate the percent-to-goal? Would I do this by adding 100 to each result and to the scale - so that the new range would be 0-200, and the target would be 115? Or would this skew the results too greatly? Example:

Score of -30: $\frac{(-30+100)}{(15+100)} = 60.9\%$

Score of 30: $\frac{(30+100)}{(15+100)} = 113\%$

Or would it be better to collapse the scale to be 0-100? Though I'm not sure how I would accomplish this. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand. Can you provide more context? Is this a math question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach is to add something to your scale to make the bottom value zero.  In your example, add $100$ making the scale $[0,200]$.  Then if the goal was $15$ it is now $115$ and take your percentages by dividing by $115$.  This is a well defined algorithm.  Whether is gives results that approximate your intuitive vision of "percent to goal" is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Great point - it's really our decision if this portrays the results we need. I just wanted to make sure I was thinking logically in adding 100 to the base to make the scale more reasonable. Thanks for the answer!